# Vue.js v-for each object text with in an array or objects

Tags: arrays, object, vue.js, couchdb, v-for

I want to list out the text that is inside an array containing objects. I dont seem to be able to work out how to address this I can get close...

for example

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="(value, index) in otherclients" v-bind:key="index">
        DATA = {{ value.doc.notes }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex'

export default {
  name: 'Viewer',
  computed: mapState({
    otherclients: state => state.otherclients
  })
}
</script>

<style lang="css" scoped></style>
```

will output

- DATA = [ { "id": "w5fpn80fnnf5nxdj9f1n1i", "text": "Welcome new
  device mydoc_android", "owner": "YOU", "deleted": false }, { "id":
  "w5fpn80fnnf5nxdj9f1wwwn1i", "text": "android 2", "owner": "YOU",
  "deleted": false } ]
- DATA = [ { "id": "c1ds7zqd7tcgig0b1xs1q", "text": "Welcome new device mydoc_ios", "owner": "YOU", "deleted": false }, { "id":
  "nf5nxdj9f1dwwen1iw5fpn80fn", "text": "More Text", "owner": "YOU",
  "deleted": false }  ]

but what I want is

- Welcome new device mydoc_android
- android 2
- Welcome new device mydoc_ios
- More Text

But I cant seem to work out the best way to access into this final layer.
Any pointers appricaited. This is part of a bigger project so structure is set for state.otherclients and quite complex.

Comment: Can you do this? `DATA = {{ value.doc.notes[0].text }} DATA = {{ value.doc.notes[1].text }}`

Comment: Thanks I tried this and the 1 one became undefined. Answer below worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nested `for` loop with `template` tag

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <template v-for="(value, index) in otherclients">
         <li v-for="(note, note_index) in value.doc.notes">{{note.text}}</li>
      </template>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
var app = new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 data:{
  name:'niklesh',
  otherclients:[
    {doc:{notes:[ { "id": "w5fpn80fnnf5nxdj9f1n1i", "text": "Welcome new device mydoc_android", "owner": "YOU", "deleted": false }, { "id": "w5fpn80fnnf5nxdj9f1wwwn1i", "text": "android 2", "owner": "YOU", "deleted": false } ]}},
    {doc:{notes:[ { "id": "c1ds7zqd7tcgig0b1xs1q", "text": "Welcome new device mydoc_ios", "owner": "YOU", "deleted": false }, { "id": "nf5nxdj9f1dwwen1iw5fpn80fn", "text": "More Text", "owner": "YOU", "deleted": false } ]}},
  ]
 }
});

//[[{text:'test11'},{text:'test12'}]},[{text:'test21'},{text:'test22'}]}]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
      <ul>
      <template v-for="(value, index) in otherclients">
        <li v-for="(note, note_index) in value.doc.notes">{{note.text}}</li>
      </template>
      </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: just a quick addition ? expects v-bind:key' directives and note_index is not used?

Comment: why did you nest a template in a template as well ?

Comment: As I said I used nested , its okay to use `template` inside `template` according to our use. we use `template` to handle loop/display condition. I remove `v-bind` is not supported in template. even `note_index` is not used I added to maintain you code syntax.